# Node.JS - Encoding images in base64 using Buffer

Tags: json, node.js, base64

I'm trying to encode an image using base64 in Node.JS to pass along to the PostageApp API as an attachment. I thought I had it working but it attaches a 1K file that isn't exactly what I was looking for.

Here's my code:

```
 var base64data;

 fs.readFile(attachment, function(err, data) {
   base64data = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
 });
```

And here's the part of the API call I am making:

```
 attachments: {
   "attachment.txt" : {
     content_type: "application/octet-stream",
     content: base64data
   },
 }
```

I'm a bit lost, not being so great with Node, but I thought it would work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Jim Schubert, that advice is wrong AND bad. First, readFile reads the whole file, not chunks. Second, blocking code would block the entire server, stupid idea.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
fs.readFile(attachment, function(err, data) {
   var base64data = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
   [your API call here]
});
```

It takes some time until the results are there, so by the time you've got the data, the outer scopes execution is already over.

Comment: Unfortunately, I pass `base64data` into a payload, which is essentially a JSON hash, which I then POST to the API server. Would this be preferable to what I'm doing?

Comment: @JonLim, this is basically the only way to do it. You'll have to do all that stuff ("pass base64data into a payload, which is essentially a JSON hash, which I then POST to the API server") inside the callback.

Comment: Ah. No other way around it? That sucks, cause the attachments parameter is optional, so if there are no attachments, it doesn't get included. Thanks though!

Comment: @JonLim, in that case, create a named function for your callback and fire it directly if there are no attachments.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Another quick question though: what if I had multiple files to attach?

Comment: @JonLim For multiple attachment, you should create multiple promises to read those files and could call PromiseAll - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_array) is deprecated

Answer (score 13):

Just specify "base64" as the encoding. [Per the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback):

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

```
fs.readFile(attachment, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err, base64data) {
   [your API call here]
});
```

Comment: Isn't encoding for readFile the encoding of the attachment and not what you want to encode to?

Comment: in the document,
`The encoding can be any one of those accepted by Buffer.` though it is of `createReadStream`. I've tried what @hyphenthis said and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2023, I found this solution to be useful because the accepted answer is now deprecated. Use `new Buffer.from` along with `base64` parameter instead of `new Buffer` does the trick.

```
base64data = new Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('base64');
```